# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes randomly

Tags: 20.04, freeze, crash

My pc freezes randomly, sometimes on boot screen, sometimes when I start visual studio code or compile any code.
The pc gets totally unresponsive. I always have to force shutdown.

1. CPU : intel i7-9750h
2. GPU : Nvidia GeForce GTX 1660ti
3. RAM : 16GB
4. Swap Memory: 2GB

I ran `journalctl —lines=100` to check the logs. Everything was fine ( white color means fine I guess)
Except for the last line (in yellow color)

`controlC0: Process ‘/usr/sbin/alsactl-E HOME=/run/alsa -E XDG_RUNTINE_DIR=/run/alsa/runtime restore 0’ failed with exit code 99`